# RabbitMQ in Docker - user creation not persisted

Tags: rabbitmq, docker

I've got a problem where the user `user1` is not persisted in the container that I have created using the following Dockerfile. What is the reason for this? Is this a RabbitMQ specific issue? e.g. I have to explicitly specify that a user must be persisted

```
FROM dockerfile/rabbitmq

# Define mount points.
VOLUME ["/data/log", "/data/mnesia"]

# Define working directory.
WORKDIR /data

RUN (rabbitmq-start &) && \
  sleep 10 && \
  rabbitmqctl add_user user1 password1 && \
  rabbitmqctl set_user_tags user1 administrator && \
  rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p / user1 ".*" ".*" ".*"  && \
  sleep 10 && \
  rabbitmqctl stop && \
  sleep 10
# Define default command.
CMD ["rabbitmq-start"]

# Expose ports.
EXPOSE 5672
EXPOSE 15672
```

Answer (score 19):

I know it's an old question, but struggled for hours with this problem today and finally solved it for me: 
The issue seems to be due to the default hostname changing at every new container with Docker, and RabbitMQ actually binds the configuration to the host name.

I set the NODENAME variable in /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf  before setting up the user:

```
# make the node name static
RUN echo 'NODENAME=rabbit@localhost' > /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf
```

and now it works.

Hope it can help.

**EDIT:**

Here is a working **Dockerfile** (copying a rabbitmq-env.conf file to the container):

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN groupadd -r rabbitmq && useradd -r -d /var/lib/rabbitmq -m -g rabbitmq rabbitmq

# add rabbitmq repo
RUN apt-get update && \
apt-get install wget --assume-yes && \
wget https://www.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-signing-key-public.asc && \
sudo apt-key add rabbitmq-signing-key-public.asc && \
sed -i -e '1ideb http://www.rabbitmq.com/debian/ testing main\' /etc/apt/sources.list && \
apt-get update && \
apt-get install rabbitmq-server --assume-yes

# Enable plugins
RUN rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management && \
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_web_stomp && \
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_mqtt

# expose ports
# Management
EXPOSE  15672
# Web-STOMP plugin
EXPOSE  15674
# MQTT:
EXPOSE  1883


# configure RabbitMQ
COPY ["rabbitmq-env.conf", "/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf"]
RUN chmod 755 /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf

# Create users for the apps
COPY ["rabbitmq-setup.sh", "/tmp/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-setup.sh"]
RUN mkdir /var/run/rabbitmq && \
chmod -R 755 /var/run/rabbitmq && \
chown -R rabbitmq:rabbitmq /var/run/rabbitmq && \
service rabbitmq-server start && \
sh /tmp/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-setup.sh && \
rm /tmp/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-setup.sh && \
service rabbitmq-server stop

# start rabbitmq
USER rabbitmq
CMD ["rabbitmq-server", "start"]
```

My **rabbitmq-env.conf** file:

```
NODENAME=rabbimq@localhost
```

My **rabbitmq-setup.sh**:

```
rabbitmqctl add_vhost myvhost && rabbitmqctl add_user myuser mypasswd && rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p myvhost myuser ".*" ".*" ".*" && rabbitmqctl set_user_tags myuser administrator
```

Comment: Could you share your Dockerfile? I am looking to find a solution for the same problem. My users do not get persisted.

Comment: @Marco: sure, see my edited answer ;)
You'll probably have to expose the ports you need and enable/disable plugins.

Comment: Note that you need to be careful if you generate your files with Windows. Make sure that all files only use LF line endings. I just needed 1+ hour to figure out that rabbitmq was looking for a hostname called "localhost\R" (rabbitmq-env.conf).

Answer (score 0):

I do something similar and it persists:

```
RUN service rabbitmq-server start ; \
    rabbitmqctl add_vhost /sensu ; \
    rabbitmqctl add_user sensu sensu ; \
    rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p /sensu sensu ".*" ".*" ".*" ; \
    service rabbitmq-server stop
```

Are you sure the creation process occurs in the first place?  The sleeps and subshells don't make it obvious.

Comment: Yes, I tried building an image using your code, and inspect the list of user using `docker exec -ti rmq rabbitmqctl list_users` and couldn't find the newly created user. Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm not a rabbitmq expert at all, sorry.  I'd try to search the rabbitmq logs for hints.

Answer (score 0):

Because many people are still having this problem (including me), what I did was:

At *building*, copy the RabbitMQ database_dir at /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit\@$(hostname) to /root (everything in /root stays persisted) after configuring all users.

At *runtime*, copy the database dir back from /root to /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia.

Only disadvantages: changes made to the database in RabbitMQ will be reset at runtime. I found no other way to do this with docker-compose however.

Configure.sh (as RUN command in Dockerfile):

```
echo "NODENAME=rabbit@message-bus" > /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf
echo "127.0.0.1 message-bus" >> /etc/hosts #prevents error that 'message-bus' node doesnt exist (this doesnt persist in /etc/hosts)
rabbitmqctl add user ... #etc
rabbitmqctl stop
mkdir /root/rabbitmq_database
cp -R /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit\@message-bus/* /root/rabbitmq_database
```

Runtime.sh (as entrypoint in Dockerfile):

```
#copy database back from /root
mkdir -p /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit\@message-bus
cp -R /root/rabbitmq_database/* /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit\@message-bus
rabbitmq-server
```

Answer (score -1):

For what it's worth, something similar is done in [this dockerfile](https://registry.hub.docker.com/r/litch/rabbitmq/dockerfile), but I can't get it to persist either:

```
RUN /usr/sbin/rabbitmq-server -detached && \
    sleep 5 && \
    rabbitmqctl add_user bunnyuser my_pass1 && \
    rabbitmqctl add_user bunny-admin my_pass2 && \
    rabbitmqctl set_user_tags bunny-admin administrator && \
    rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p / bunnyuser ".*" ".*" ".*"
```